# issues adding print drivers (Xerox 3250, 4510, 8560) to a terminal server so I can print from it

Tags: drivers, terminal, printer, services

After remoting into another company's site (using Open VPN) and connecting to a machine their end to access their Accounts databases, I realised my printers hadn't been carried over by Terminal Services.

First guess was a GPO was stopping the printers redirecting - which turned out to be correct.
Disabled the GPO, still didn't work.

Checked Event Viewer on the remote machine and there were errors stating that it could not find drivers for the relevant printers.

The driver install files that I would use to install the machine locally normally don't contain any .inf files meaning I can't just add a fake printer and point it to the drivers just once to get it installed...

Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of Windows is hosting the Terminal Server?

Answer (score 0):

Give the [Xerox Universal Print driver](https://www.support.xerox.com/en-ca/product/global-printer-driver/downloads?platform=wins2003) (link for Windows 2003 version) a try, one of it's main intentions is simplify and reduce the number of drivers in use on print and terminal servers.

The driver will have to be installed into the TS, and you may have to use it on your local computer as well, to ensure that the TS knows that the drivers match and in turn uses it for the redirected printer(s).

If you are using a Windows 2008 TS, you may want to check out it's built-in [Easy Print](https://web.archive.org/web/20151118040854/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/rds/archive/2007/04/26/introducing-terminal-services-easy-print-part-1.aspx).